# querySelectorAll + closure + addEventListener don't get me working mutually-exclusive checkboxes

Tags: javascript, dom-events, closures

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span id="ctl00_0" class="mutuallyExclusiveCheckBoxList">
        <input id="ctl00_0_0_0" type="checkbox" value="1">
        <label for="ctl00_0_0_0">Option 1</label>
        <input id="ctl00_0_1_0" type="checkbox" value="2">
        <label for="ctl00_0_1_0">Option 2</label>
      </span>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <span id="ctl00_1" class="mutuallyExclusiveCheckBoxList">
        <input id="ctl00_1_0_1" type="checkbox" value="1">
        <label for="ctl00_1_0_1">Option 1</label>
        <input id="ctl00_1_1_1" type="checkbox" value="2">
        <label for="ctl00_1_1_1">Option 2</label>
      </span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Above is an HTML snippet generated by ASP.NET WebForm (simplified for clarity). As is framework generated code, I can not modifiy it's structure except for adding the `mutuallyExclusiveCheckBoxList` class.

I want to make the `checkbox`es within same `span` mutually exclusive (checking one option uncheck others) with following JS code, but with no luck:

```
function makeCheckboxesMutuallyExclusive(checkbox, checkboxes) {
    return function () {
        if (!checkbox.checked) return;
        for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
            if (checkboxes[i] !== checkbox && checkboxes[i].checked)
                checkboxes[i].checked = false;
        }
    }
}
function mutuallyExclusiveCheckBoxLists() {
    var containers = document.querySelectorAll('span.mutuallyExclusiveCheckBoxList');
    for (var i = 0; i < containers.length; i++) {
        var checkboxes = containers[i].querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');
        for (var j = 0; j < checkboxes.length; j++) {
            var uncheckOthers = makeCheckboxesMutuallyExclusive(checkboxes[j], checkboxes);
            checkboxes[j].addEventListener('change', function () { uncheckOthers(); });
        }
    }
}
mutuallyExclusiveCheckBoxLists();
```

Checkboxes in the 1st row don't get mutually exclusive. Checkboxes in the 2nd row work only when I check Option 1 then Option 2 (which automatically uncheck Option 1 as I intend), not the other way round (Option 1 becomes uncheckable when Option 2 already checked).

I guess it's something about JS closure, but I think I've done as [it needs to be](https://stackoverflow.com/a/750506) (the "classic" solution because I need IE compatibility). I don't know where I did wrong.

Hope someone enlighten me.

Comment: "Mutually exclusive checkboxes" -- you mean radio buttons? Why go through all this when there's a native element that does it for you? `<input type="radio" name="ctl00_0"><input type="radio" name="ctl00_0">` Mutually exclusive.

Comment: Even if you care about IE, give yourself a rest: Write code in ES6+ and let [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) transpile that for you.

Comment: That is not a closure, use `let` to define the variables of the loops. [Here is a working version](https://jsfiddle.net/9fx6mLha/)

Comment: @HereticMonkey Because the options need to be able to be all unchecked. Radio buttons can't do that.

Comment: You can add a radio that indicates "none." Much easier than making checkboxes mutually exclusive.

Comment: @InSync As I said what I'm working on is an ASP.NET WebForms app, not a modern front-end project. I don't know how to incorporate Babel in this scenario.

Comment: @Titus Is `let`/`const` absolutely necessary? I want to avoid them for legacy browser consideration.

Comment: @InSync Did you close my question? If you did (or, to the person who did it), would you please at least indicate me where in the link the solution I need (supporting older IE) is? As stated in my question I've read the same link and tried the solution in the accepted answer but just can't figure out what went wrong. Easily closing my question without clear explanation/indication just turns me helpless.

Comment: I did not. Have you checked out the fiddle linked above by Titus? If that works for you, just [go ask Babel](https://babeljs.io/repl) for a transpilation (specify `ie 6` or whatever browser at the *Targets* box).

Comment: Actually, it is somewhat of a closure, you can fix your example by using `checkboxes[j].addEventListener('change', uncheckOthers);`. The problem is that all the event listeners callbacks will call the same `uncheckOthers` function if you use `function() { uncheckOthers() }`. Because you've used `var`, the *global* `uncheckOthers` variable value will have the value of the last definition.

Comment: @Titus I got it. Thank you for your help. InSync also.